# Close tab if user moves to another tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).blur(function(){
    if(seconds!=0) {
        window.opener.location.href="link";
        self.close();
    }
});
```

But this code makes parent window moves to the above url if an alert box is open, Is there any way so the tab only close if user moves to another tab not on opening alertbox.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to manipulate browser tabs through client-side Javascript. If, however, you are developing a Chrome Extension you can use `chrome.tabs.remove()` and `chrome.tabs.create()`

Comment: Not likely. Once you move away from window javascript has no access to where you go

Comment: @Carpetfizz:  self.close() works fine on popups, like the one the code shown uses...

Comment: @dandavis, right sorry, I meant for when the current tab is not active, then the Javascript code won't have access to others like charlietfl said